# UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions and Multithreading

Tags: ios, multithreading, uikit, core-graphics

I'm a bit confused about `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` and threading because according to [UIKit Function Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html) `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` should be called only on the main thread. When called it creates a bitmap-based context, which is ready to be manipulated either with CoreGraphics' functions or with methods like -`drawInRect:` for `UIImage`, `-drawInRect:withFont:` for `NSString` and so on. For CoreGraphics' drawing everything is clear - you pass a CGContextRef argument that is being manipulated to every function, but the UIKit drawing methods use the current context in the stack. In the release notes of [What's New in iOS 4.0](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iPhoneOS4.html) it's written that

> **Drawing to a graphics context in UIKit is now thread-safe.** Specifically:
>   - The routines used to access and manipulate the graphics
>   context can now correctly handle contexts residing on different
>   threads.
>  - String and image drawing is now thread-safe.
>  - Using color and
>   font objects in multiple threads is now safe to do.

So far so good. The interesting part is that I have a project, where I do some intensive drawings and create multiple images by creating context with `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`, but when these operations happened to be more time-consuming and I just moved the drawing in a background thread and when ready display them on the screen with some animations and everything works just fine - no crashes, no leaks. Images draw as they are expected and it seems that `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` creates a context for the background thread and everything seems to be fine.
So my questions are:
 - Why it's necessary to call `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` only on the main thread as it seems to be working fine in background?
 - How to use `UIImage`'s `-drawInRect:` method for example, in a background thread, where I don't have a current context and I can't seem be able create one because I can't call `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` there?
 - What's is the correct approach to background image manipulation using UIKit's methods (I know I can also use `CGBitmapContextCreate`, but it neither pushes the created context into the context stack nor I seem to be able to do it myself in order to use `-drawInRect:` method of `UIImage`)?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

So, after a couple of days of investigating, how come manipulating the UIKit context is thread-safe and yet you don't seem to be able to create one in a thread other than the main because `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` "should be called only on the main thread", but still doing so works perfectly fine and after reading some small posts on the subject and discussing it with other guys on Apple's developer forums I can clearly state that, what's said in the documentation about `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`, `UIGraphicsPushContext` and `UIGraphicsPopContext` is **WRONG** and those methods could be called and the context used in another thread without problems. So `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`, `UIGraphicsPushContext` and `UIGraphicsPopContext` are **thread-safe**.

Comment: I can confirm this. This was a documentation error in iOS5 SDK and earlier (if you have access to WWDC 2012 videos, check session 211 and iOS6 SDK docs).

Comment: It's also super important to call UIGraphicsEndImageContext() or things start to get wacky with the CPU.

Comment: The documentation has been fixed: `In iOS 4 and later, you may call this function from any thread of your app.`

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer: Use `UIGraphicsPushContext` to push your own CG context to the top of the "UIKit context" stack and everything (from that thread, as I interpret Apple's documentation) will paint to that. Don't forget to use `UIGraphicsPopContext` to pop it from the UIKit context stack.

This applies to all UIKit drawing operations; for example drawing `UIImage`s, like you asked. Push a context, draw, then pop the context.

Comment: That's was one of my ideas, but unfortunately the docs says: `You should call this function from the main thread of your application only.` both for `UIGraphicsPushContext` and `UIGraphicsPopContext`

Comment: I can't recall which and I can't find it, but I saw these things covered in great detail in a WWDC video from 2011 or 2010. My intuition from what I remember is that some of the documentation is subtly misleading and that it will all work out in some sane way if you just follow a few rules from the video. (I wouldn't expect you to bet the farm on this advice, but I think that if you found the video it would answer your questions.)

Comment: I'll take a look now and will write down an answer.